# 2sxc Edit UI no longer appears

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

My DNN site is running 7.4.2 and I'm running the latest 2sxc, 08.05.06. I have this strange issue where when I try to edit any content items, instead of displaying the edit dialog, it's now just displaying a bunch of javascript.

Before: [image: http://screencast.com/t/dlbdtAobTFu]

After: [image: http://screencast.com/t/v2UhmjOEGfd]

As far as I know nothing has been deliberately changed on the site and I'm not seeing any errors in the browser console related to the module. No errors are showing in the Event Log either. I've tried reinstalling the latest release overtop to try to repair anything that may have been corrupt or missing but that didn't solve the issue. Any ideas what might be happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript inside the ui.html seems to show, instead of run. I believe that this file is somehow damaged, that the `script` tag isn't open/closing correctly.

-- correction --

To anybody reading this - it turned out that the web-server of this user was reconfigured, causing HTML files to be handled as plain-text. So this was a user bug.

Comment: @Josh - pls close this as answered.